# Array comprehension of array-valued function in Julia - inner dimensions somehow removed?

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia

I am confused about the following behaviour of Julia when using array comprehensions that have arrays/matrices in them. They seemingly seem to bury the other dimensions of the inside array. I am looking to get an array of dimension `2,4,3` in the end.

```
myarr = Array{Float64}(undef,4,3)
broken_off_dim = [myarr for i in 1:2]
size(broken_off_dim)
```

Somehow, I get `(2,)` and I wonder what happened to the inner dimensions? Can you help modify the above code so that `(2,4,3)` comes out? I tried reshaping but that throws an error.

Functions that are applied over a specific margin also do not work properly then.

Comment: Hi Keynes! The issue is that `broken_off_dim` is a vector of Matrices, so when you're looking for the length of the vector, it is going to come back with 2. Are you wanting a 2, 4, 3 matrix? or a 2, 4, 3 vector?

Comment: If you wonder why a vector of matrices doesn't just act like a 3d array, then consider the case `A = [zeros(2,3), zeros(4,5)]`. What would be the size of `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a comprehension to make one array rather than an array of arrays, then you probably want `stack`.

```
julia> vv = [[i, 2i, 3i] for i in 1:4]
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [2, 4, 6]
 [3, 6, 9]
 [4, 8, 12]

julia> mat = stack(vv)  # inner dimension(s) go first
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3   4
 2  4  6   8
 3  6  9  12

julia> mat == stack([i, 2i, 3i] for i in 1:4)
true

julia> mat == stack((i, 2i, 3i) for i in 1:4)
true
```

Notice that it accepts an un-collected comprehension generator too, without making the `Vector{Vector{T}}` first. In fact almost any iterator of iterators.

With more dimensions, all dimensions are preserved. (I think the example above probably wants `stack(myarr(i) for i in 1:2; dims=1)`.)

```
julia> vm = [[i 10i; 2i 21i] for i in 1:4]
4-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [1 10; 2 21]
 [2 20; 4 42]
 [3 30; 6 63]
 [4 40; 8 84]

julia> vm[end]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  40
 8  84

julia> stack(vm) |> summary
"2×2×4 Array{Int64, 3}"

julia> stack(vm; dims=2) |> summary
"2×4×2 Array{Int64, 3}"
```

On Julia 1.8 or earlier, you will need `using Compat` for this.

Comment: Brilliant @mcabbott may I just ask what is the difference between `(i,2i,3i) for i in 1:4` and `[i,2i,3i] for i in 1:4` inside the stack command?

Comment: The round brackets make a Tuple instead of a Vector. This will sometimes be faster, by saving allocations. But mostly to illustrate that non-array iterable objects are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In Julia, an array-of-arrays is different from a multidimensional array. When you do `[myarr for i in 1:2]`, you're constructing an array of size 2, whose elements are `myarr`.

To get an array of size `(2, 4, 3)`, you can of course do `Array{Float64}(undef,2,4,3)` in the first place - but assuming your real use case is more complex than shown here, and doesn't allow you to construct the 3-D array right away, you can do something like this instead:

```
permutedims(repeat(myarr, 1, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2))
```

`repeat(myarr, 1, 1, 2)` makes a 3-D array from the given 2-D array by repeating the values in the new dimension. `permutedims(...., (3, 1, 2))` says "make the 3rd dimension (the one we newly added) the first, and push the other two dimensions down one place".

This results in a `2×4×3 Array{Float64, 3}`.

Comment: Ah thank you! The only thing is that the index i is part of generating myarr. Is your way still possible then? So it’s not a simple repeat operation. Thank you for clarifying the array of array issue by the way.